# Creating an object which contains unique item from a nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object, time-complexity

I have an array of objects called employees. I need a solution that will return me a list of groups and respective employees present in the group along with the group properties.
The example is below, I have used an object but the result can also be an array that has a property called groupName within an object. `[{groupName:"developer", employees:[],...}..]` As long as the response returns a list of groups with their corresponding employees.

Below is the solution I did but I need a solution with a better time complexity that is O(n).

```
const employees = [
  { "name": "John Doe",
    "id": "1",
    "groups": [
      { "id": "developerId", "name": "developer", "color": "#fff" },
      { "id": "engineerId",  "name": "engineer", "color": "#fff" }
    ],
    "groupId":["developerId", "engineerId"]
  },
  { "name": "Jane Doe",
    "id": "2",
    "groups": [
      { "id": "developerId", "name": "developer", "color": "#fff" },
      { "id": "testerId",  "name": "tester", "color": "#fff" }
    ],
    "groupId":["developerId", "testerId"]
  }
]

//Solution O(m*n)
 let groups = {};
  employees.forEach((item) => {
    item.groups.forEach((group) => {
      if (!groups[group.name]) {
        groups[group.name] = {
          employees: [item.id],
          ...group,
        };
      } else {
        groups[group.name].employees = [...groups[group.name].employees, item.id];
      }
    });
  });

//result
{
    "developer":{
        "id":"developerId",
        "employee":[
           "1",
           "2"
        ],
        "color":"#fff"
    },
    "engineer":{
        "id":"employeeId",
        "employee":[
            "1",
         ],
         "color":"#fff"
    },
    "tester":{
        "id":"testerId",
        "employee":[
            "2",
         ],
         "color":"#fff"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give us a definition of `Groups` so that I don't have to assume something?  [My IDE](https://tsplay.dev/N7O1RN) is also bad at assuming things and it's always nice to be able to just get to work on a problem instead of work on setting it up first (e.g., a [mre])

Comment: You need to consult `employes[i].groups[j]` for every `i` and `j`, don't you?  You can't skip any of them, right?  How could you do better than m×n then?

Comment: You can use "any" to avoid using types, this is a typescript solution so you can use a js instead without any types. I have edited the question anyways. @jcalz

Comment: You've got the question tagged as typescript, and it's always nice to have a [mre] where pasting the example into a TypeScript IDE doesn't have [unrelated errors](https://tsplay.dev/Nr5n1w). I don't want to avoid using types, but if you think we should be annotating `groups` as `any`, then you should do it in the example code.

Comment: Please accept an answer as the solution to close the question if solved

Answer (score 1):

Using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```js
const employees = [
  { 
    "name": "John Doe",
    "id": "1",
    "groups": [
      { "id": "developerId", "name": "developer", "color": "#fff" },
      { "id": "engineerId", "name": "engineer", "color": "#fff" }
    ],
    "groupId": ["developerId", "engineerId"]
  },
  { 
    "name": "Jane Doe",
    "id": "2",
    "groups": [
      { "id": "developerId", "name": "developer", "color": "#fff" },
      { "id": "testerId", "name": "tester", "color": "#fff" }
    ],
    "groupId": ["developerId", "testerId"]
  }
];

const groups = employees.reduce((acc, { id: employeeId, groups = [] }) => {
  groups.forEach(({ id, name, color }) => {
    acc[name] = { 
      id, color, employee: [...(acc[name]?.employee ?? []), employeeId] 
    };
  });
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(groups);
```

Comment: Good solution but the time complexity is the same, O(m*n) isn't it?

Comment: I don't think it's doable in O(n) as you need to pass the employee id to every group item somehow.

Comment: I agree, I have struggled to get the same but the problem is I will be dealing with a huge chunk of data for employees and groups. Not sure how I can improve the time complexity

Comment: Where is the data coming from? do you define the schema?

Answer (score 0):

If you like to add some speed, you could use the old fashioned `for` statement for iterating, especially of having only a single result object.

This approach does not create an object again and again and uses the already existing objects.

```js
const
    employees = [{ name: "John Doe", id: "1", groups: [{ id: "developerId", name: "developer", color: "#fff" }, { id: "engineerId", name: "engineer", color: "#fff" }], groupId: ["developerId", "engineerId"] }, { name: "Jane Doe", id: "2", groups: [{ id: "developerId", name: "developer", color: "#fff" }, { id: "testerId", name: "tester", color: "#fff" }], groupId: ["developerId", "testerId"] }],
    result = {};

for (const { id: employeeId, groups } of employees) {
    for (const { id, name, color } of groups) {
        result[name] ??= { id, color, employee: [] };
        result[name].employee.push(employeeId);
    }
}

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```